# Curved rectanglular button with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a curved rectangle in html and css, but I can't find out how. Any ideas?

```css
.scrollToTop a button {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: @fullred;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 7%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "scrollToTop">
<a href = "#top">
<button>up top</button>
</a>
</div>
```

It looks like [this](https://ibb.co/Ms91mwH), but I'm trying to shave a few pixel off the sides to make it look better.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Giving border-radius in pixels would be much better.

A number above 12px will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `%` instead use `px`:

```
border-radius: 25px;
```